# Installing node 6.10.3 as an NPM dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda, dependency-management

Working on projects using the [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) to be deployed to [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/), I'd like to be running the same version of node that is [available on AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) - namely node 6.10.3.  Adding that to ["engines"](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) has no effect, so I also added it to ["dependencies"](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies), but installing that dependency always fails:

```
> node@6.10.3 preinstall /Users/ssterling3/Documents/2017/IIT/Apps/Student Dashboard/mobile-dashboard/node_modules/node
> node installArchSpecificPackage

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for node-darwin-x64@6.10.3
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ssterling3/.npm/_logs/2017-09-15T20_58_25_281Z-debug.log
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-darwin-x64/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ssterling3/Documents/2017/IIT/Apps/Student Dashboard/mobile-dashboard/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:18:27)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node@6.10.3 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node@6.10.3 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ssterling3/.npm/_logs/2017-09-15T20_58_25_350Z-debug.log
```

This appears to be the relevant portion of the latest log file:

```
59 silly preinstall node@6.10.3
60 info lifecycle node@6.10.3~preinstall: node@6.10.3
61 verbose lifecycle node@6.10.3~preinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
62 verbose lifecycle node@6.10.3~preinstall: PATH: /opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/ssterling3/Documents/2017/IIT/Apps/Student Dashboard/mobile-dashboard/node_modules/node/node_modules/.bin:/Users/ssterling3/Documents/2017/IIT/Apps/Student Dashboard/mobile-dashboard/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/munki:/Users/ssterling3/bin:/opt/local/bin/:/Users/ssterling3/.npm-global/bin/:/Users/ssterling3/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/
63 verbose lifecycle node@6.10.3~preinstall: CWD: /Users/ssterling3/Documents/2017/IIT/Apps/Student Dashboard/mobile-dashboard/node_modules/node
64 silly lifecycle node@6.10.3~preinstall: Args: [ '-c', 'node installArchSpecificPackage' ]
65 silly lifecycle node@6.10.3~preinstall: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
66 info lifecycle node@6.10.3~preinstall: Failed to exec preinstall script
67 verbose unlock done using /Users/ssterling3/.npm/_locks/staging-9795425667a03fed.lock for /Users/ssterling3/Documents/2017/IIT/Apps/Student Dashboard/mobile-dashboard/node_modules/.staging
68 verbose stack Error: node@6.10.3 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
68 verbose stack Exit status 1
68 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
68 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
68 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
68 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
68 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
68 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
68 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
68 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
69 verbose pkgid node@6.10.3
70 verbose cwd /Users/ssterling3/Documents/2017/IIT/Apps/Student Dashboard/mobile-dashboard
71 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
72 verbose argv "/opt/local/bin/node" "/opt/local/bin/npm" "install" "node@6.10.3"
73 verbose node v6.10.3
74 verbose npm  v5.4.0
75 error code ELIFECYCLE
76 error errno 1
77 error node@6.10.3 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
77 error Exit status 1
78 error Failed at the node@6.10.3 preinstall script.
78 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
79 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

It looks like it's trying to fetch a platform-specific variant of the package, and the server doesn't have it.

No other dependencies (or devDependencies) are affected.

This is on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29), with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) 2.4.1, macports nodejs6 @6.10.3_0, and macports npm5 @5.4.0_0.

- Does [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/) really not have the matching version?
- Is it available from some other source?
- Is there something I can do to help [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/) make it available?

Comment: Maybe I'm reading your question wrong, but if you just need to install a specific version of node, you can use nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Not sure npm is intended to be used for per-project node versioning.

Comment: I'd rather not have to make everyone start using yet another package manager.  The npmjs page for the node packages gives me the impression that what I'm trying to do is exactly what it's intended for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node

Comment: If you're running on `macports nodejs6 @6.10.3_0`, then you're already running the right version.

Comment: That's just me and noone else, why force everyone to use macports and follow the arcane procedure for installing an out-of-date port?  Even if noone else mattered, every time I run `port upgrade outdated` it'll get upgraded to current, and rolling back is a pain I'd rather not have to deal with continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting the maintainer, npm package `node-darwin-x64@6.10.3` now exists, which resolves the problem.

(Lambda now also supports node 8.10.0, and the corresponding `node-darwin-x64@8.10.0` also exists.)